# An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssl, imap, mailkit

i'm trying to make a simple email viewer , but this SSL error is distracting me to continue , some emails works fine and some i get this error , like i have two yahoo emails , one account works , the other doesn't work ! it's the same imap what's the issue ?

my code :

```
 Using client = New ImapClient()


                client.CheckCertificateRevocation = False

                client.Connect(imp, 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto)

                client.Authenticate(login, pass)
                Dim inbox = client.Inbox
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.[ReadOnly])

                Dim query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"))


Dim uids = inbox.Search(query)
If uids.Count > 0 Then
'some code here
End If

client.Disconnect(True)


Catch ex As Exception
If (ex.Message.Contains("authentication failed") OrElse ex.Message.Contains("Invalid") OrElse ex.Message.Contains("Authentication") OrElse ex.Message.Contains("login failed")) Then
            
             MsgBox("wrong pass")


        ElseIf (ex.Message.Contains("Failed to connect") OrElse ex.Message.Contains("host") OrElse ex.Message.Contains(" Bad Request") OrElse ex.Message.Contains("connnection") OrElse ex.Message.Contains("ssl")) Then
             MsgBox("attempting a retry. " &  ex.Message)
           'my thread retry code
        Else
            MsgBox("unexpected error : " &  ex.Message)

        End If


End Try
```

it's simple i guess.

my errors :

```
An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The root certificate has the following errors:
  • A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.



The operation has timed out.
See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SslHandshakeException for possible solutions.

   at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.<ConnectAsync>d__108.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at email.Form1.Checker(String login, String pass, String imp, String PrxIP, Int32 PrxPrt, String PrxLogin, String PrxPass)
```

why it spams this errors without logining to the account ? and the account keeps retrying for ever , even with rotating proxies !

**i added C# since i can translate to vb.net**

Comment: Check the webpage for each mail server.  The Port number and properties like "enable ssl" may be different at each mail server.   Usually the mail server has a webpage for SMTP that list the require properties.  Most email server use SSL, but if you are using a company email server behind a firewall (which is secure) you may not need SSL and can use the unclassified port 25 with SSL disabled.

Comment: *"like i have two yahoo emails , one account works , the other doesn't work ! it's the same imap "* - so you are using `imap.mail.yahoo.com` in both cases as the IMAP server you are trying to reach, with same program on same machine? Or what exactly is different here?

Comment: no difference , same machine same software same proxy , or even different proxies doesn't work @SteffenUllrich

Comment: @jdweng ,is there's a away i can check if the no SSL option is better ? because i have long imap list on the same settings

Comment: *"same proxy , or even different proxies"* - proxy? There is nothing about a proxy in your question or code. Note that a proxy might work as a man in the middle for TLS, thus causing the problems you see. *"long imap list"* - this does not sound like same server is used but that you check various different servers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah i have an imap list with the correct proxy prettymuch , that's why i don't know what's the issue since some accounts work and some doesn't

Comment: "terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider" seems quite clear to me: the SSL certificate is issued by an untrusted provider (maybe self-signed?), I can only think that perhaps you are connecting to different servers each time. A Wireshark trace would help immensely in diagnosing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config --> httpruntime --> framework version, if it is less than 4.7 it does not support tls1.2 which might be the issue.

Comment: The error message clearly points to certificate validation which is unrelated to the TLS protocol version

Comment: i only have app.config , `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />`

Comment: That's right, as Steffen mentioned, it is SSL issue from the error message it looks like the certificate is not trusted, might have to add the certificate to certificate chain. the link explains how to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/communications-server/dd441378(v=office.13)

Comment: The error message may not be certificate.  The error message indicates just that TLS has failed.  The failure may occur if you are using Net for TLS and encryption mode is not supported in Net.  Or if the operating system doesn't support the TLS encryption mode (normally in older operating systems or in Linux that isn't using latest kernel version).

Comment: @JohnMartin can u send me a link that explains better than microsoft please ? i want to try maybe that's the issue

Comment: You can use Internet Explorer to add the certificate and see if it works. Important : Disable Antivirus since sometimes they change the certificate name while being installed.

Comment: @JohnMartin add it to the pc or my software

Comment: 1) Start Internet Explorer running as a user with administrative privileges.
2) Browse to domain (ignore certificate warnings) if any.
3) Click the ”Certificate Error” text in the top of the screen and select ”View certificates”
4) In the Certificate dialog, click Install Certificate -> Next
5) Select Place all certificates in the following store -> Browse
6) Check Show Physical Stores check box

Comment: 7) select Trusted Root Certificate Authorities, Expand the plus sign and select Local Computer, If Local Computer does not show up then select Trusted Root Certificate Authorities  OR (If the above does not work) choose Trusted People, Expand the plus sign and select Local Computer. 
8) Click OK – Next – Finish – OK 
9) Restart Internet Explorer to verify it works.

Verify if this works after running the application

Comment: TLS is performed before the HTTP Request is sent. Exception indicates that TLS did not complete. It does not indicate the reason. If you read the exception carefully it just gives possible reason for the failure.  Exception message says it can either be a certificate issue or a timeout.  Do not be fooled and think the only reason is the certificate.  The typical failure mode for TLS is the connection did not complete.  You cannot tell the reason.  The connection fails due to the encryption not passing and like any encryption method you cannot tell what caused the encryption/decryption failure.

Comment: @JohnMartin it's not the ssl certificated

Comment: @jdweng what are the possibilites ? maybe my code takes alot of time to process ? or if this email has too much emails ? maybe it timing out before it finishes the task ?

Comment: i just need a hint of what's wrong with my code so i can fix it @jdweng

Comment: The best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark.  The sniffer will show TLS version that is being used.  The client request the version of TLS.  Then server sends a Certificate Block with names of possible certificates that can be used.  The client then looks up in the stores the certificate names.  TLS will fail if certificate name is not found. You can also open the certificate with notepad and check the expiration date and the encryption mode.  An encryption mode that is not valid for TLS 1.2 will also cause a failure.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: You must use TLS 1,2 or TLS 1.3.  SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and are disabled at server.  There are also issue when you are using Net before 4.7.2.  Or with older operating systems that do not support the encryption mode in certificate.  Best when using Net 4.7.2 or later and the project file is using the operating system as the default for TLS.  The issue is not your code.  It is either the project settings, the operating system, or the certificate not loaded properly at both client and server.

Comment: checked wireshark it uses TLS1.1 with that imap

Comment: maybe i need to use https proxy or socks ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this TLS code before call ImapClient.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```